# how to replicate the unix stat command in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Does anyone have clues on how to replicate the unix stat command in Python? I wasn't sure how to find the various elements of the file attributes that the stat command usually provides.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.stat).